# Passing Value of label to JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dom

> I want to insert label of radio button to database.

```
<form method="post" action="sendToDB.jsp" name="testForm">

<input name="AnsOption" class="input_txt" type="radio">Option1  
<input name="AnsOption" class="input_txt" type="radio">Option2
<input name="AnsOption" class="input_txt" type="radio">Option3
    
<input id="sub" type="submit" value="Submit">           
</form>
```

**OR**

```
<form method="post" action="sendToDB.jsp" name="testForm">
    
    <input name="AnsOption" class="input_txt" type="radio"><label>Option1</label>   
    <input name="AnsOption" class="input_txt" type="radio"><label>Option2</label>
    <input name="AnsOption" class="input_txt" type="radio"><label>Option3</label>
        
    <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Submit">           
    </form>
```

I want to retrieve the value of label in JSP page.

```
String option1= request.getParameter(<Value Of Each Labe l>);
String option2= request.getParameter(<Value Of Each Labe 2>);
String option3= request.getParameter(<Value Of Each Labe 3>);
```

How can I do it?

**EDIT:**
Label of radio button should be dynamically changeable so `value` attribute of radio button is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "value" attribute on the desired input to retrieve it server side.

```
<input name="AnsOption" class="input_txt" type="radio" value="Option1"><label>Option1</label>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more with an example